# Как сделать правильные проверки discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я сделал бота, который создаёт логи почти всех действий на сервере, но есть проблема, когда пользователь включает/выключает микрофон, то бот пишет, что он отключился и подключился к серверу, хотя у меня нет даже проверок на это, как избавиться от этого, пытался через `if len(before.channel.members) == len(after.channel.members):`, но так не работает.

```
if before.channel is not None:
        if before.channel.id == 720295133282566176:
            embed=discord.Embed(
                title='',
                description=f' Пользователь {member.mention} покинул AFK канал.',
                color=0xf04848
            )
            embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} • Сегодня, в {now.hour}:{now.minute}')

            await bot.get_channel(1000781163696230440).send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(
                title='',
                description=f' Пользователь {member.mention} покинул голосовой канал `{before.channel}`',
                color=0xf04848
            )
            embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} • Сегодня, в {now.hour}:{now.minute}')

            await bot.get_channel(1000781163696230440).send(embed=embed)

    if not before.afk and after.afk == True:
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title='',
            description=f' Пользователь {member.mention} был перемещён в AFK канал.',
            color=0xfaa41b
        )
        embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} • Сегодня, в {now.hour}:{now.minute}')

        await bot.get_channel(1000781163696230440).send(embed=embed)

    if member.voice and after.afk == False:
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title='',
            description=f' Пользователь {member.mention} присоединился к голосовому каналу `{member.voice.channel}`.',
            color=0x44b37f
        )
        embed.set_author(name=f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}', icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'ID: {member.id} • Сегодня, в {now.hour}:{now.minute}')

        await bot.get_channel(1000781163696230440).send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что функция `on_voice_state_update` вызывается каждый раз, когда пользователь обновляет свой `discord.VoiceState`, из-за чего она вызывается в том числе когда пользователь выключает микрофон и т.д. Решается это 1м условием `if before.channel != after.channel`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before: discord.VoiceState, after: discord.VoiceState) -> None:
    if before.channel != after.channel:
        if before.channel is None and isinstance(after.channel, discord.VoiceChannel):
            print(f'member "{member.name}" connected')
        elif isinstance(before.channel, discord.VoiceChannel) and isinstance(after.channel, discord.VoiceChannel):
            print(f'member "{member.name}" moved')
        elif isinstance(before.channel, discord.VoiceChannel) and after.channel is None:
            print(f'member "{member.name}" disconnected')
```

Кстати для этого нужно включить определённый intent при создании объекта бота:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.voice_states = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)
```